Different HTTPS response in container and host machine using same CURL command in Docker
This morning i have encountered a weird issue in my Docker. I was trying the following on the Host machine
curl --location 'https://widgets.sir.sportradar.com/translations/en.json' --header 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' --header 'Accept: */*' --header 'Connection: keep-alive' --header 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --verbose

and it worked perfectly fine without any issue and i see a JSON response aswell.
But when i run the same command inside the Docker (a container, with no proxy, no https proxy, and even Docker is not behind a proxy) , i see the following response
# curl --location 'https://widgets.sir.sportradar.com/translations/en.json' --header 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' --header 'Host: widgets.sir.sportradar.com' --header 'Origin: widgets.sir.sportradar.com' --header 'Accept: */*' --header 'Connection: keep-alive' --header 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --verbose
 *   Trying 23.15.33.210:443...
 *   Trying 2600:1417:3f::1728:28a8:443...
 * Immediate connect fail for 2600:1417:3f::1728:28a8: Network is unreachable
 *   Trying 2600:1417:3f::1728:2871:443...
 * Immediate connect fail for 2600:1417:3f::1728:2871: Network is unreachable
 * Connected to widgets.sir.sportradar.com (23.15.33.210) port 443 (#0)
 * ALPN, offering h2
 * ALPN, offering http/1.1
 *  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
 *  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
 * TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
 * TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Finished (20):
 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
 * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Finished (20):
 * TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
 * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
 * TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
 * SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
 * ALPN, server accepted to use h2
 * Server certificate:
 *  subject: C=AT; ST=Wien; L=Wien; O=Sportradar Media Services GmbH; CN=widgets.sir.sportradar.com
 *  start date: Sep 12 00:00:00 2024 GMT
 *  expire date: May 14 23:59:59 2025 GMT
 *  subjectAltName: host "widgets.sir.sportradar.com" matched cert's "widgets.sir.sportradar.com"
 *  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1
 *  SSL certificate verify ok.
 * Using HTTP2, server supports multiplexing
 * Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
 * Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
 * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
 * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
 * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
 * Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x559081b41eb0)
 * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
> GET /translations/en.json HTTP/2
> Host: widgets.sir.sportradar.com
> user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
> origin: widgets.sir.sportradar.com
> accept: */*
> connection: keep-alive
> cache-control: no-cache
> 
 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
 * old SSL session ID is stale, removing
 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
 * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
< HTTP/2 403 
< server: AkamaiGHost
< mime-version: 1.0
< content-type: text/html
< content-length: 410
< expires: Fri, 13 Sep 2024 08:03:33 GMT
< date: Fri, 13 Sep 2024 08:03:33 GMT
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains ; preload
< 
 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>
 
You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;widgets&#46;sir&#46;sportradar&#46;com&#47;translations&#47;en&#46;json" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;7ec21160&#46;1726214612&#46;dd56e61
<P>https&#58;&#47;&#47;errors&#46;edgesuite&#46;net&#47;18&#46;7ec21160&#46;1726214612&#46;dd56e61</P>
</BODY>
</HTML>
 * Connection #0 to host widgets.sir.sportradar.com left intact

Now, if we do the same request on our Host machine but add the header X-Forwarded-Proto: https the request would fail on the host machine aswell and we will see the same error "Access Denied".
Note that the response for "Access Denied" says "http://" instead of the "https://" scheme.
Now if we run the same container but network mode to host , and run the curl command, it will work perfectly fine in the container aswell.
This means that somehow docker is interfering with the requests and adding additional headers maybe?
My docker-compose is as below
    testprogram:
    build:
    context: ./testprogram/
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
    - HTTP_PROXY=
    - HTTPS_PROXY=
    - NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,testprogram,nginx
    volumes:
    - /etc/ssl/certs:/etc/ssl/certs
    ports:
    - "8989:8989"
    restart: always
    networks:
    - backend
    - frontend
    deploy:
    resources:
    limits:
    cpus: "4"
    memory: 2048M


The weird issue is that the curl command works on host machine and in container only if network mode is host but if network mode is not set, the request fails in the container.
What could be missing here?

This site is behind Akamai CDN and is probably using its bot protection. This protection does not simply work by checking User-Agent, but might check TLS fingerprint, header order, browser-specific headers like Sec-Fetch-..  and then generate some likelihood for being a bot using a combination of such signals - with ML or heuristics. curl on your desktop likely shows different signals as curl in your docker. For example I can access this URL through the browser but not with curl - on the same system.

But the weird thing is that this same thing worked for sometimes on my windows development machine, i tried  same docker setup there, it worked for a few times until it got blocked. What could potentially be a workaround to this, i know network mode to host can work but that adds up another layer of service, which is sort of unnecessary.

A reason might be that the bot detection is not a static algorithm but includes history information. For example if something behaves kind but not fully like a bot and then does this again and again the system might decide after a while that this is likely a bot. This is just speculation of course - the exact methods used by Akamai to detect bots are not open (keeping these secret is part of a successful detection) and also evolve continuiously.
